# Azure Speech To Text in Blazor app (C# SDK)

Tags: c#, blazor, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use the Speech C# SDK with Blazor, but even in the simplest of examples I always get NoMatch.

```
var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
switch (result.Reason) // <-- Here I get ResultReason.NoMatch
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.
Geo

Answer (score 1):

The method for RecognizeOnceAsync uses the default system microphone and mine was bad, when I set my default microphone to the correct one in Windows 10, the SDK started working as intended.